# Redux Reducer: Is this an acceptable way to toggle a Boolean from the initial state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

I have an array of objects as the initial state. This array holds user question/response data. On the HTML page there is a material-ui switch toggle to control whether the question should be public or private. I know redux recommends keeping logic in the action not reducer but this is the solution I came up with. Is the "toggleSwitch reducer" an acceptable solution or have I created an anti-pattern?

Note I am using a 'reducer helper' instead of a 'switch statement' to reduce boilerplate code.
Thank you in advance. I am very new to redux.

```
// ACTION
export const toggleQuestion = (questionId) => {
    return {
        type: TOGGLE_QUESTION,
        payload: {
            questionId
        }
    }
}




//REDUCER 
const initialState = [{
        id: '1',
        firstName: 'James',
        lastName: 'Smith',
        question: 'Ask a question here?',
        response: 'This is an answer to the question',
        public: true,
        created: '2019-23-11T01:50:00+00:00',
        modified: null
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        firstName: 'Taylor',
        lastName: 'Johnson',
        question: 'Ask another question here?',
        response: 'Here is another answer to another question',
        public: true,
        created: '2019-23-11T01:50:00+00:00',
        modified: null
    }
];


const toggleSwitch = (state, payload) => {
    return [
        ...state.map((item) => {
            if (item.id === payload.questionId) {
                return Object.assign(item, {
                    public: !item.public
                })
            }
            return item
        })
    ]
}

export default createReducer(initialState, {
    [CREATE_QUESTION]: createQuestion,
    [UPDATE_QUESTION]: updateQuestion,
    [DELETE_QUESTION]: deleteQuestion,
    [TOGGLE_QUESTION]: toggleQuestion
});




// HELPER TO CREATE THE REDUCER
export const createReducer = (initialState, fnMap) => {
    return (state = initialState, {
        type,
        payload
    }) => {
        const handler = fnMap[type];

        return handler ? handler(state, payload) : state
    }

}
```

Comment: Side note: You are mutating the state with that `Object.assign`. It should be `Object.assign({}, item, {
                    public: !item.public
                })`. Also, I believe the use of `[ ...state.map(---) ]` is redundant. You can remove the brackets and just use `state.map(---)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is *if you do the same thing 10 times in a row, do you get the same result?*

Reducers should be pure, free of any side effects, meaning the same input, produces the same output, every single time.

Based on your example, it looks to me like the same action, against the same state should produce the same output, so I would say yes, I don't see any problem with that.

You could however extract that logic to an effect that simply instructs the state as part of the update what the new value should be.

It's not clear what framework you are using, but React has Saga's and Thunks and Angular has NgRX that gives you a 'safe' place to apply side effects outside of the reducer.

I quite often use [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) to create schemas of data, much like a database. I then use `selectors` to do a lot of the heavy lifting from my store for my components. This allows me to keep my reducers quite simple and only really concerned with changes to the props they handle.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful